# Unable to shorten flow field vectors

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have this program where I'm trying to make a flow field. I wanted to use the vectors I use to make the noise to be available for the particles moving through the flow field, so they can use it to accomplish that. But I'm running into a problem: my flow field lines are very lenghty: [image]

I'm doing soemthing like this: [image]

And I'm unable to shorten the vector used to discover the dynamic vertex position.
Does someone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I just had to multiply the vector by a number using a `scale` function, like so:

```js
const noiseVec = scale(GRID_LINE_SCL, normalize(vec2(Math.cos(noiseValue), Math.sin(noiseValue))));
```